# Best way to upload video on twitter

Tags: java, video, twitter

I have to upload video to twitter (post a tweet text with video) from my java application. I use twitter4j to upload images and it works perfectly. I'm confused about the best way to upload video. I have found in this link https://github.com/mrisney/twitter-java-ads-sdk/blob/master/src/examples/VideoUploadExample.java the code that implements the
twurl command but I want to know if it's possible to upload video with twitter4j
like I have done for the image? Or have I to use the twurl way to do it? 
And is there any possibility to post video directely on twitter?

This is what I do for the image upload

```
     `  Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(accessTokenStr,
                accessTokenSecret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(text);
        statusUpdate.setMedia("New pic", new URL(photo).openStream());
        twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate.inReplyToStatusId(tweetId));`
```

Thanks

Comment: Shall you show the code how to upload video using twitter4j @LIg

Comment: hi @Llg, I am also facing the same problem in uploading video. please share your knowledge..

Comment: @KoVartthan and GraceVenkat sorry for being late. Since the last time I worked on this (in 2016) I remember that twitter4j doesn't support the video upload. So i didn't include it in my application. I suggest you to read the twitter API documentation to see if there is a simple way to upload videos to Twitter from a JEE application.

Comment: @GraceVenkat please read my previous comment

Comment: @Llg Thanks it works by using twitter4j by modifying the code but unfortunately it does works in twitter sdk

Answer (score 0):

Send the video with `uploadMediaChunked`, get the media ID and then use `setMediaId` on your media.

**Example (Kotlin):**

```kotlin
val status = StatusUpdate("Hello, World!")

val mediaChunked = twitter.uploadMediaChunked("file_name.mp4", File(assetsFolder, "file_name.mp4").inputStream())
status.setMediaIds(mediaChunked.mediaId)
```

You *need* to use `uploadMediaChunked`, if you use `uploadMedia` Twitter will reject your status/media!